# Finding only values which are consecutive identical characters

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a column from which I would like to retreive only those values which are only consecutive identical characters like 'ppp' 'mmmm', 'ddddd'. The length of the string will be greater than or equals to 3

I tried different queries but somehow it's not giving me the output

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to do this in MySQL. It can be done with regular expressions that support back-references, but MySQL's regexp library doesn't.

Comment: You can write a stored function that loops over the characters in a string and checks if they're all the same.

Comment: show what you've tried.  If nothing else, it gives us a great starting point, knowing what your table and column names are and what else is in your query.

Comment: I tried this query but it is showing me  invalide escape sequence erro: SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(column_name, '([A-Za-z0-9])\\1{2,}') > 0

Comment: @Nuz That's what I said above: MySQL doesn't have back-references, so `\\1` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Use `CREATE FUNCTION` to define a function that just loops over the characters. If any of them are not equal to the first character, return FALSE. If you get to the end of the loop, return TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply some tricks. Begin by using the `LEFT` string function to extract the first character. Then, replace occurrences of that character with an empty value using either the `TRIM`, `REPLACE`, or `TRANSLATE` functions. Verify that the resulting string is empty. Finally, validate the length of the string using the `LENGTH` (or `LEN`) function. Consider the following SQL queries, which incorporate these techniques:

```
SELECT name
FROM items
WHERE TRIM(LEFT(name, 1) FROM name) = '' AND LENGTH(name) >= 3
```

```
SELECT name
FROM items
WHERE REPLACE(name, LEFT(name, 1), '') = '' AND LENGTH(name) >= 3
```

I have tested the idea with MySQL, and it worked as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO items VALUES
  (1, 'abcd'),
  (2, 'aa'),
  (3, 'gggggggggg'),
  (4, 'CCCC'),
  (5, 'k'),
  (6, 'ffffff');

SELECT name
FROM items
WHERE TRIM(LEFT(name, 1) FROM name) = '' AND LENGTH(name) >= 3

-- Output:
-- gggggggggg
-- CCCC
-- ffffff
```

Additionally, if your SQL engine supports regex and capturing groups, you can implement it using patterns such as `(.)\1{2,}`. Even if capturing groups is not supported, you can still combine the `LEFT` function with regex patterns to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Hi, I tried this one but it's showing unexpected 'from' error

Comment: Can you please provide me with your MySQL version? [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) is a comprehensive list of string functions available, along with their respective syntax. I have also included an example demonstrating the usage of the "REPLACE" function. Kindly give it a try and verify if it functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative uses a recursive query to split each string to individual characters, then aggregates and filters on the count of distinct characters.

Assuming that your table has a structure like `mytable(id, str)`:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id, str, 
        char_length(str) as max_pos
        1                as pos,
        null             as car 
    from mytable
    union all 
    select id, str, max_pos, pos + 1, substring(str, pos, 1)
    from cte 
    where pos <= max_pos
)
select id, str
from cte
group by id, str
having count(car) >= 3 and count(distinct car) = 1
```

Note that recursive queries are supported in version 8.0 only.